# How does Google Chrome for Mobile display websites like Youtube and Twitch?

Tags: java, android, flash, google-chrome, youtube

Google Chrome for android, is able to display videos on sites such as Youtube and Twitch without any flash support. What I want to know is how Chrome does this, through a plug-in of some sort? What I also want to know is how I could replicate the results, because I've been searching for flash support or support for playing videos that normally require flash (Mainly twitch/youtube), for Java/Android, and haven't been able to find a solution.

Thanks for your help!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Google Chrome for mobile does not rely on flash to play videos. Instead, it streams the videos from the site and plays them with a special player from the device.

As for replicating these results, I would recommend using a VideoView. Here is an example:

```
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    setContentView(R.layout.main);
    String videourl = "http://something.com/blah.mp4";
    Uri uri = Uri.parse(videourl);
    Intent intent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_VIEW, uri);
    intent.setDataAndType(uri, "video/mp4");
    startActivity(intent);
}
```

Make sure the URL is a direct link to the video. (it must end in .mp4)

Comment: Thanks for the answer, I think I accepted it :) However since I'm a new user I am unable to upvote. This answer was exactly what I was looking for however, so thank you very much!

What do ya know... After posting this comment I have 15 reputation! Just enough to upvote!

Comment: The code above, if I'm not mistaken is for android? Can you give me code for a native Java App if I were to do the same? Or maybe a link to a tutorial that can? Thanks!

Comment: Thanks! The code above is for android. Yeah, I could give you a java native version, but you would need a lot more than this. Look into something called Swing, it allows you to make GUIs in java.

Comment: Yeah I understand the basics of swing, but I want to know how to get the video player... Like is it a swing component that I don't know? Or is it a special component

Answer (score 0):

For Flash videos there is a special format. These Files often have the file postfix .flv. There are also Players like VLC on all PC plattforms, which have the ability to encode these Files. It's just a format like mp4, avi etc. And like said before, Android devices have a special app for decoding flash videos.